# imagemagick and automator DPI change

Tags: macos, imagemagick, automator

I am trying to create a workflow in automator to change DPI from 72 to 300, so that I can use it on any image in Finder (when i right click on the image, then I can run the action).

When I run the command in terminal, it works fine:

```
mogrify -units PixelsPerInch *.jpg  -density 300 *.jpg
```

However, when I use it in shell script, it does not work, and I can't figure out why. This is what I have so far:

```
for f in "$@"
do
       /opt/ImageMagick/bin/mogrify mogrify -units PixelsPerInch *.jpg  -density 300 *.jpg
done
```

[Screenshot from Automator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd3Xg.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have put `mogrify` twice. You just need `/opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert "$f" -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 "$f"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am a novice at this, hence those mistakes. Now it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mogrify` is for batch conversion (thus your `*.jpg`in the working version) but in your example, you have created a loop to step through files. You don't seem to be using your `f` variable at all. 
You should get the command to work on individual files using the `convert` command instead of `mogrify` and then plug in`$f`wherever the filename would occur.